# Unable to put footer in the correct place - Holy grail layout - bootstrap grid

Tags: css

I tried positioning the footer in holy grail layout using bootstrap grod, but I am unable to do so. I tried everything

I tried positioning the footer in holy grail layout using bootstrap grod, but I am unable to do so. I tried everything
I tried positioning the footer in holy grail layout using bootstrap grod, but I am unable to do so. I tried everything

Could someone help with this?
`    
    
    
        
       
            html,
            body {
               height: 100%;
               width: 100%;
            }

```
       .container-fluid {
           border: 5px solid plum;
        }

        .main-row {
            border: 5px solid orangered;
        }

        .left-sidebar {
            border: 3px solid teal;
        }

        .nav-bar {
            border: 3px solid crimson;
        }

        .main-right-sidebar {
            border: 3px solid khaki;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        .main-bar {
            border: 3px solid greenyellow;
        }

        .right-sidebar {
            border: 3px solid turquoise;          
        }

        .footer {
            border: 3px solid deeppink;
        }

        .cont {
            border: 3px solid brown;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 main-row">
            <div class="col-2 h-100 left-sidebar">
            </div>

            <div class="col-8 h-75 main-right-sidebar">
                <div class="col-12 h-25 nav-bar">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 h-75 main-bar">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-2 h-75 right-sidebar">
            </div>

            <div class="col-10 h-25 footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to offset your footer.

```
<div class="col-md-10  offset-md-1 h-25 footer">
            </div>
```